# Continuous function on compact metric space has minimum and maximum

Tags: continuity, compactness

Let's have continuous function $F$, $B$ - closed ball around some point $x_0$ with radius $\rho$, and some set $J$.
$$\max_{t∈J,x∈B(x_0,ρ)}||F(x,t)||$$

We have one theorem which says that continuous function on compact set has minimum and maximum.

In this case, we have function with two variables. Since we have $B$, which is closed set, do we have to take $J$ to be compact (or just closed), so we can talk about maximum of the function $F$?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking in $\Bbb R$, let say $F$ is define on $D \subset\Bbb R^2$.

So $(x,y)\in D$ if and only if $x\in J \wedge y\in B_{(x_0,p)}$.

For continuous function on compact metric space to has minimum and maximum, you are asking $D$ to be compact, cause $F$ is define on $D$.

$B$ or $J$ to be compact is not enough.

Comment: Is it enough if we have closed $B$ and compact $J$?

Comment: You need D to be compact. If B is closed but goes to infinite, then D is not compact. You need them both B and J to be compact.

Comment: To the proposer: In metric spaces in general, a closed ball $B$ need not be compact, so $B\times J$ may fail to be compact. For example if $J =\{p\}$  and $B$ is not compact, there exists an unbounded continuous $f:B\to \Bbb R,$ so let $F(x,p)=f(x)$ for $x\in B$.